# Edit wpf datagrid row after filtering

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I have a WPF C# datagrid which I can filter through with an SqlDataAdapter and display it with the ItemsSource property.

I can also update/delete rows before filtering but not after.

```
diamedbEntities objContext;
Sender objSendToEdit;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    objContext = new diamedbEntities();
    dgEmp.ItemsSource = objContext.Senders;
}

private void dgEmp_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{       
    objSendToEdit = dgEmp.SelectedItem as Sender;
}

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (objSendToEdit == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot delete the blank Entry");
    }
    else
    {
        objContext.DeleteObject(objSendToEdit);
        objContext.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted..");
    }
}
```

After filtering objSendToEdit is null.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Should look at the CollectionViewSource, it makes filtering simple. I have an example of it on my website here: http://www.jarloo.com/excel-like-autofilter-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=VS.100).aspx

> The as
>   operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion is not
>   possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

What are you trying to do with `objSendToEdit = dgEmp.SelectedItem as Sender;`?

Comment: objContext.DeleteObject(objSendToEdit);
objContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: Alright, let me rephrase that, why are you casting the `SelectedItem` to the type of `Sender`?

Comment: Sender is the database table which populates the datagrid.It works fine before I filter the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

This is because filter must be clearing the selection thus making `objSendToEdit` null.

You should re-select the `objSendToEdit` back onto the data grid immediately after filtering.

```
  objSendToEdit = dgEmp.SelectedItem;
  //// filter code
  dgEmp.SelectedItem = objSendToEdit;
```

Let me know if this helps.